# How to fix 'all the data from same id into one row'?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to convert rows into columns using `Case` statement and it worked but I have repetitive id's.

```
000001  NULL    NULL    NULL    12075000.000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
000001  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10500000.000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
000001  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10500000.000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
000001  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10500000.000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
000001  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10500000.000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
000001  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10500000.000    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

The first column is the `id` column and the others represent the months. As you can see the `id`'s are the same. Is there a way to display the data in one single row for each id for all 12 months ?

```
SELECT CID,
    (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2018-08-16' THEN BALANCE end) AS SHRAWAN,
    (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2018-09-16' THEN BALANCE end) AS BHADAU,
    (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2018-10-17' THEN BALANCE end) AS ASHOJ,
    (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2018-11-16' THEN BALANCE end) AS KARTIK,
    (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2018-12-15' THEN BALANCE end) AS MANGSHIR,
    (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-01-14' THEN BALANCE end) AS POUSH,
    (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-02-12' THEN BALANCE end) AS MAGH,
    (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-03-14' THEN BALANCE end) AS FALGUN,
    (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-04-13' THEN BALANCE end) AS CHAITRA,
    (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-05-14' THEN BALANCE end) AS BAISHAKH,
    (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-06-16' THEN BALANCE end) AS JETH,
    (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-07-17' THEN BALANCE end) AS ASHAD
    FROM 
    (SELECT R.BR, R.CID, E.EOMDate, SUM(E.BALANCEAMT) AS BALANCE
    FROM T_EOMHIST E 
        LEFT JOIN T_RELACC R ON E.Acc = R.Acc AND E.BR = R.BR AND E.APPTYPE IN ('1','3')
        LEFT JOIN T_GLLINK G ON G.BR = E.BR AND G.Code = E.GlCode AND G.CoopRep01 = 'Y' and G.TableId in ('10','30')
        LEFT JOIN T_GLCONTROL H ON H.BR = E.BR 
    WHERE H.FinYear = '2018' AND E.EOMDate BETWEEN H.FinYrStartDate AND H.FinYrEndDate 
        AND R.TYPE = '010' AND R.AppType IN ('1','3') 
        AND CID = '000001'
        GROUP BY R.BR, R.CID, E.EOMDATE)T 
    WHERE CID = '000001'
```

This is the code for the select query.

Expected result is single row record for same column. Show `NULL` if only there isn't any data. I've tried using the `GROUP BY` clause too, but its showing some error saying aggregated functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CID,
    SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2018-08-16' THEN BALANCE end, 0)) AS SHRAWAN,
    SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2018-09-16' THEN BALANCE end, 0)) AS BHADAU,
    SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2018-10-17' THEN BALANCE end, 0)) AS ASHOJ,
    SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2018-11-16' THEN BALANCE end, 0)) AS KARTIK,
    SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2018-12-15' THEN BALANCE end, 0)) AS MANGSHIR,
    SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-01-14' THEN BALANCE end, 0)) AS POUSH,
    SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-02-12' THEN BALANCE end, 0)) AS MAGH,
    SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-03-14' THEN BALANCE end, 0)) AS FALGUN,
    SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-04-13' THEN BALANCE end, 0)) AS CHAITRA,
    SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-05-14' THEN BALANCE end, 0)) AS BAISHAKH,
    SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-06-16' THEN BALANCE end, 0)) AS JETH,
    SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-07-17' THEN BALANCE end, 0)) AS ASHAD
FROM FROM 
    ...
GROUP BY CID
```

Or, if you need NULL instead of 0:

```
NULLIF(SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2018-08-16' THEN BALANCE end, 0)), 0) AS SHRAWAN
```

Comment: Also is there a way to set date by checking month instead of adding the actual date ? Like month '08' represents SHRAWAN, '09' represents BHADAU within the CASE statement ?

Comment: CASE WHEN MONTH(EOMDATE) = [put your number here]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
   SELECT CID, 
    sum(isnull(SHRAWAN, 0)) AS SHRAWAN,
        sum(isnull(BHADAU, 0)) AS BHADAU,
        sum(isnull(ASHOJ, 0)) AS ASHOJ,
        sum(isnull(KARTIK, 0)) AS KARTIK,
        sum(isnull(MANGSHIR, 0)) AS MANGSHIR,
        sum(isnull(POUSH, 0)) AS POUSH,
        sum(isnull(MAGH, 0)) AS MAGH,
        sum(isnull(FALGUN, 0)) AS FALGUN,
        sum(isnull(CHAITRA, 0)) AS CHAITRA,
        sum(isnull(BAISHAKH, 0)) AS BAISHAKH,
        sum(isnull(JETH, 0)) AS JETH,
        sum(isnull(ASHAD, 0)) AS ASHAD    
        from (
    SELECT CID,
        (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2018-08-16' THEN BALANCE end) AS SHRAWAN,
        (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2018-09-16' THEN BALANCE end) AS BHADAU,
        (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2018-10-17' THEN BALANCE end) AS ASHOJ,
        (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2018-11-16' THEN BALANCE end) AS KARTIK,
        (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2018-12-15' THEN BALANCE end) AS MANGSHIR,
        (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-01-14' THEN BALANCE end) AS POUSH,
        (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-02-12' THEN BALANCE end) AS MAGH,
        (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-03-14' THEN BALANCE end) AS FALGUN,
        (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-04-13' THEN BALANCE end) AS CHAITRA,
        (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-05-14' THEN BALANCE end) AS BAISHAKH,
        (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-06-16' THEN BALANCE end) AS JETH,
        (CASE WHEN EOMDATE = '2019-07-17' THEN BALANCE end) AS ASHAD
        FROM 
        (SELECT R.BR, R.CID, E.EOMDate, SUM(E.BALANCEAMT) AS BALANCE
        FROM T_EOMHIST E 
            LEFT JOIN T_RELACC R ON E.Acc = R.Acc AND E.BR = R.BR AND E.APPTYPE IN ('1','3')
            LEFT JOIN T_GLLINK G ON G.BR = E.BR AND G.Code = E.GlCode AND G.CoopRep01 = 'Y' and G.TableId in ('10','30')
            LEFT JOIN T_GLCONTROL H ON H.BR = E.BR 
        WHERE H.FinYear = '2018' AND E.EOMDate BETWEEN H.FinYrStartDate AND H.FinYrEndDate 
            AND R.TYPE = '010' AND R.AppType IN ('1','3') 
            AND CID = '000001'
            GROUP BY R.BR, R.CID, E.EOMDATE)T 
        WHERE CID = '000001'
        ) as t
        group by t.CID
```

Comment: Nope its saying "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'."

Comment: Also is there a way to set date by checking month instead of adding the actual date ? Like month '08' represents SHRAWAN, '09' represents BHADAU within the CASE statement ?